# Extended BNF grammar optional [...] notation

Tags: ebnf

I read somewhere `[x],y` in this notation, `x` is optional, but I could not understand what is meant by *optional*. Does it means, there can be `y` or `x,y` or something else? Can anyone give some example about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Documentation about `[]`:

> Optional: The items between `[` and `]` are optional. All or none of the items in the brackets are included.

In [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) `[]` stands for optional parameters that can be ommitted, so `[x],y` defines the possibilities `y` and `xy`.

Example:

```
Bicycle_Accessories = saddle [bell | horn] {water_bottle_holders}
```

defines next possibilities:

```
saddle 
saddle bell 
saddle horn 
saddle water_bottle_holder 
saddle bell water_bottle_holder 
saddle bell water_bottle_holder water_bottle_holder
```

Comment: Actually, `[x],y` can be either `,y` or `x,y` -- the `,` doesn't mean anything other than a `,`.  If you want `y` or `x,y` you need `[x,]y`.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Comma `,` is a concatenation in EBNF, not a typical symbol.